# Visual Studio 2008 Designer hangs for about 22 seconds

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008 just recently started hanging up when I first go into a form in the  designer. It hangs for about 22 seconds and then lets me continue. It just started doing this on my pc for a couple weeks now all of a sudden.

I do use I disabled all add-ins and macros using the Visual Studio Options.

Any ideas what could be causing this or how to find out?

Comment: Here's what I've found:
There are no user controls on the form. It even does this if I open a blank form with no code.
It freezes only when I open Visual Studio, open first form in the designer, and click on the form or a control on the form. I just hangs for about 30 seconds.
I tried changing the Options to what was suggested, but to no avail. I am about ready to give up on this.

Comment: this kind of problems is normal behavior of microsoft's softwares

Answer (score 1):

Have you got any user controls that do any Design Time rendering or operations?

Alternatively, have you got the latest [service packs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)?

If you do have anything slow running at design time, you can add the following to stop it:

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
   // Your slow design time code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the code in the forms doing? Visual Studio will run at least the constructor of your form when going to design mode - are you doing anything that might time out/fail/etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is rebuilding its control bar. You are probably seeing your mouse cursor change to a cog wheel with an arrow for the whole duration.

Check out step 6 of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations/8453#8453) and see if it help.